# How does concurrency per queue work in sidekiq?

Tags: redis, sidekiq

If I have two queues, default and critical, and a concurrency set to 10, does that mean that each of the individual queues is going to run 10 concurrent threads to execute the jobs stored that are queued up in the Redis database?

Or maybe threads is the wrong terminology to use here?

Answer (score 0):

Each Sidekiq process will create 10 threads.  Concurrency is how many jobs each process can work on at the same time.

A queue is an array of jobs in Redis.